# How can I select a component and be able opt for sub components

Tags: inno-setup

I ask for help .
How do I on page components , subdividor components . eg

When you select " N " in the 1st combo box , option will be in the 2nd combo box " BGVC " ; " PNGM "; " NRV ;" " BGC "

if you select " P " in the 1st combo box , option will be in the 2nd combo box " MAI " ; " PRT " ; " SMF "; " AVR "

ie if I select a component I can choose 4 sub components .

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in native Inno using `[Components]` and the `exclusive` flag. It won't give you a drop down for the sub components though.

```
[Components]
Name: "N"; Description: "N"; Flags: exclusive;
Name: "N\BGVC"; Description: "BGVC"; Flags: exclusive;
Name: "N\PNGM"; Description: "PNGM"; Flags: exclusive;
Name: "N\NRV"; Description: "NRV"; Flags: exclusive;
Name: "N\BGC"; Description: "BGC"; Flags: exclusive;
Name: "P"; Description: "P"; Flags: exclusive;
Name: "P\MAI"; Description: "MAI"; Flags: exclusive;
Name: "P\PRT"; Description: "PRT"; Flags: exclusive;
Name: "P\SMF"; Description: "SMF"; Flags: exclusive;
Name: "P\AVR"; Description: "AVR"; Flags: exclusive;
```

[image: screenshot of the Components page]

If you want to use multiple dropdowns, you will need to create these yourself in `[Code]`. You can use the [`CodeDlg.iss`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Examples/CodeDlg.iss) example as a base.